# How to connect two mobile phones directly?

Tags: android, ios, networking, mobile

I often use chat software on mobile phone, such as ICQ, MSN, etc. It seems these softwares all need a central server to relay the messages. It's kind of like a star topology. I am wondering if there's a way to connect devices together without such central server. I.e. a true network topology.

### Update

I may not make my question clear. I am wondering if there's any application that can connect phones without through a central server. Maybe communication in a P2P way.

Comment: have you tried Bluetooth?

Comment: That sounds like regular TCP to me. Maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: I know Bluethooth, but the distance is too near.

Comment: You can use `Bluetooth`. But aside from that using a server is pretty much inevitable. If you want to connect over the internet you have to know the IP of the phone you want to contact. And to find out the IP you need some kind of server where the phones can register there IP. This is how for example Skype works, but Skype uses a lot of other trickery too and the way they handle those P2P connections is very complex. Most other apps relay there messages through a server because it is much simpler. You can look into [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

The architecture is as follows

Every phone has a SocketServer listening to connection

Every phone has a BroadCastReceiver that listens to a change in the data connection (if the 
connection is lost or created).

Every phone can create Sockets to communicate to the other phones
A server that has a mapping of client-ids and client-ips

Now the basic flow is as follows

When a client(phone) connects to the the internet, a BroadcastReceiver notices this change and sends a message to the server telling him his ID and IP
The server receives this and as a respone returns a list IDs (the ids of the other logged users).

The connection is done vía java Sockets, I built a simple protocol for sending params similar to http syntax, a message has this form:

{my_id}:{methodName}?param1=val1&param2=val2&...&paramN=valN.

In case a complex object needs to be sended I use GSon to send a param as a whole object.

When a client sends a message he must specify the sender's id. He then asks the server for the id and then the server replies with the ip (This ip is then cached in the client with a simple  mapping).

The message is received by the server who then notifies any MessageReceivedListeners

The advantage of doing it like this are:

No need for a complex server: Mobile App developers (like me) usually don't want to spend much time on the server side.
Phones usually connect and disconnect from mobile networks very often so a mechanism for re-establishing the connection is usually needed (In this case, the BroadcastReceiver is the one who notifies the server that his IP has changed and the other phones just ask the server).

Its a simple protocol, so parsing is quite fast, but if needed, complex objects can be sent through GSon

It separates concerns: The app never knows the IP of the other phones, just their id's, which in my case are the actual Facebook ID's of the users.

The "methoName" which I mentioned earlier in the protocol syntax makes MessageReceivedListeners suscribe to only one "methodName", so they only receive messages that are relevant to them.

Any suggestions and critics are welcome

Answer (score 3):

When two clients are behind a NAT , which is the case for almost every smartphone and regulare PC (not servers or devices with globally valid ip addresses), they cannot communicate without a third entity, which maps the client_name to it's ip.
So, from a practical point of view, it cannot be implemented using IP addressing. But other solutions maybe NFC and Bluetooth, which are both proximity-oriented.